# Error in last line of msxml program

Tags: c++, com, msxml

I'm using MSXML 4.0 for parsing my xml.

The program works fine, but just before the program terminates I get the following exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x00417be5 in
>   db2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
>   reading location 0x00b1c740.

at `comip.h` at `_Release()` method at line `m_pInterface->Release();`

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Database.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <objbase.h>
#import <msxml4.dll>

using namespace std;


void main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom;
    HRESULT hr= pXMLDom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument40), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER); //Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0 

    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
      printf("Failed to instantiate an XML DOM.\n");
      //return 0;
    }

    try
    {
        pXMLDom->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
        pXMLDom->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
        pXMLDom->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;

        if(pXMLDom->load("users.xml") == VARIANT_TRUE)
        {
            printf("XML DOM loaded from users.xml:\n%s\n", (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->xml);
        }
        else
        {
            // Failed to load xml
            printf("Failed to load DOM from stocks.xml. %s\n",
                   (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->parseError->Getreason());
        }
        ::CoUninitialize();
    }
    catch(_com_error errorObject)
    {
        printf("Exception thrown, HRESULT: 0x%08x", errorObject.Error());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        printf("Unknown error");
    }   
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my program. It just throws an exception before the last line.

Can someone point me in a right direction?

**Edit :** Strange I removed `::CoUninitialize();` from my program and it works fine.

What is wrong with `::CoUninitialize();` method ?

Thanks,

Comment: It is most probably a memory error. Debug it, you should see it. **And why aren't you catching exceptions by reference instead of making copies ?**

Comment: @DumbCoder I'm new to c++ so I don't know how to catching exceptions by reference, can you give me an example?

Comment: @DumbCoder I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Use catch(_com_error& errorObject). For reference http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implicitly using COM after you have called `CoUninitialize`. This is done in the destructor of `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr`, which calls the function `IXMLDOMDocument::Release`.

`CoUninitialize` must be the absolute last COM function ever been called.

Make these changes, and it will work. I've made sure that `CoUninitialize` will be called after the destructor of `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr`:

```
void XMLDomTest()
{
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom;
    HRESULT hr= pXMLDom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument40), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER); //Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0 

    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
      printf("Failed to instantiate an XML DOM.\n");
      return;
    }

    try
    {
        pXMLDom->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
        pXMLDom->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
        pXMLDom->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;

        if(pXMLDom->load("users.xml") == VARIANT_TRUE)
        {
            printf("XML DOM loaded from users.xml:\n%s\n", (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->xml);
        }
        else
        {
            // Failed to load xml
            printf("Failed to load DOM from stocks.xml. %s\n",
                   (LPCSTR)pXMLDom->parseError->Getreason());
        }
    }
    catch(_com_error errorObject)
    {
        printf("Exception thrown, HRESULT: 0x%08x", errorObject.Error());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        printf("Unknown error");
    }   
}

void main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    XMLDomTest();
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```